# Spring Security OAUTH2 authorization and resource server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

after logging in the form i get 404 error instead of being redirected to frontend

here is the authorization server configs:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServer {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(resource -> resource.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withUsername("kaua")
                .password("1234")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("client")
                .clientSecret("secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:5173/")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                        .requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder()
                        .refreshTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofHours(10))
                        .build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
```

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurity {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
                // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
                // authorization server filter chain

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
                        .allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

and here from the resource server:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurity {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).oauth2ResourceServer(resource ->
                        resource.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
                        .allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

`spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080`

I hope it redirects to the front end so that I can get the access token and save it in the frontend and even later create a login using social providers

logs, I put it in the gist because it exceeds the stack overflow limit: https://gist.github.com/Kaua3045/9860707db1260cad40702dc74e551d12

Comment: Please add debugging details. You can enable trace logging via `logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace`.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I added and edited with the trace there [Trace](https://gist.github.com/Kaua3045/9860707db1260cad40702dc74e551d12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues I see based on your code and logs.

First, if you need CORS support, make sure to add `http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())` to your security configuration (both filter chains in auth server).

Second, according to your logs, you are not calling `/oauth2/authorize`. The first request is to `/login`, which redirects to `/` on authentication success. Since the `/` endpoint does not exist, you receive a 404 error. The real issue seems to be on the client, and could also be CORS-related, but you are missing those details in your question.